# browse array in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

i try to access items on my array, let me explain :
it returns me very good values when I print in my page twig

```
{{statistics}}
```

i have this result :
[{"today":[1,0],"lastmonth":[2,1],"todayWomen":[1,0],"lastmonthWomen":[2,1],"todayMen":[0,0],"lastmonthMen":[0,0],"todayUnique":[1,0],"lastmonthUnique":[1,1],"todayWomenUnique":[1,0],"lastmonthWomenUnique":[1,1],"todayMenUnique":[0,0],"lastmonthMenUnique":[0,0]}]

in my app.js

```
    var statistics = [];
$http.get('/ajax/statistics').success(function(data){
    angular.forEach(data, function(value,key){
        if (value != "ok") {
            statistics.push(value);
        };
    });
    $scope.statistics = statistics
});
```

but when i try to access item by item with ng-repeat and $index it appears to me only the index elements 0

```
        {% verbatim %}
        {{statistics}}
        <div ng-repeat="stat in statistics">
                <h3>Les visites globales de l'établissement n° : {{$index}} !!</h3>
                <li> Nombre de personnes qui ont visité aujourd'hui est :   {{stat.today[$index]}} </li>
        </div>
        {% endverbatim %}
```

when i try with hard code it's ok

```
            {% verbatim %}
        {{statistics}}
        <div ng-repeat="stat in statistics">
                <h3>Les visites globales de l'établissement n° : {{1 or 0}} !!</h3>
                <li> Nombre de personnes qui ont visité aujourd'hui est :   {{stat.today[1 or 0]}} </li>
        </div>
        {% endverbatim %}
```

any help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you provide an working example?

I tested a similar example out in plunkr, and it seems to work. Could not reproduce.

http://plnkr.co/edit/uPuD6xyVvpiSJJQUf9aS?p=preview

Using `{{stat.today[$index]}}`

**EDIT 1:**
Here is only 1 iteration, still works http://plnkr.co/edit/v81Gp5rmE3rVGQB1d1WK?p=preview

**EDIT 2:** Elements in array, here you go http://plnkr.co/edit/QiSoWPIzZj62E2jYdD9G?p=preview

Comment: but he posted only once when he should be 6 iteration in the example you give me

Comment: Here is only 1 iteration, still works http://plnkr.co/edit/v81Gp5rmE3rVGQB1d1WK?p=preview

Comment: I misspoke, I wanna hope find out how we calculate the number of élément in today array, that is, for the example that you gave me this will be 2 items, Thank you very much

Comment: Elements in array, here you go http://plnkr.co/edit/QiSoWPIzZj62E2jYdD9G?p=preview

Comment: and if I want to display the array elements
as in the example you have given me to see i want to have : 100 200, I did that but it does not work, <div ng-repeat="stat in statistics">
        <div ng-repeat="elt in stat.today.length">
            <td>{{stat.today[$index]}}</td>
        </div>
</div>

Comment: I did not understand, what do you want to do exactly?